# std::queue memory consumption leads to memory leak - C++ ?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory, stl, queue

The following codes didn't release the memory consumed for 3000 elements even  after i pops out all the elements from the qInt queue. What is the reason ?

```
std::queue<int> qInt; //Step01: Check the running memory

for (int i=0;i<3000;i++)
{       
    qInt.push(i);
}
//Step02: Check the running memory it should have been increased    

while(!qInt.empty())
{
    qInt.pop();
}
//Step03: Check the running memory expecting Step01 memory but it is still the same of Step02
```

Comment: Are you checking the memory consumption using the task manager?

Comment: @Borgleader Yes of course

Comment: You never know, you just might push 3000 more items into that queue. If you want best-chance for releasing the heap memory its holding in preparation for that impending assumption, swap it with a local empty automatic.

Comment: @WhozCraig You suggested a way like this. 
    std::queue<Int> empty;
    std::swap(qInt, empty );
It is pretty ok if i want empty the whole queue. Lets say whenever i use pop, how can i reduce the memory allocated for pushing 3000 elements ?

Comment: @Carthi See rerun's answer and links. It (they) explain it better than I can in-comment.

Comment: If you are using Task Manager to check memory usage, even if the memory is release from use by the data structure, it will not be returned to the operating system until the program finishes.

Answer (score 9):

By defalut std containers do not deallocate memory once they have reserved it.  The std::queue is generally implemented on type of std::dequeue which offers [shrink_to_fit](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/deque/deque/shrink_to_fit/).  If you are not using c++ 11 use the [swap idiom](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Shrink-to-fit).

Comment: Can you please suggest a sawp idiom to std::queue ?

Answer (score 2):

if you release/free/delete a heap memory . it doesn't mean that the memory consumption will immediately come down . the memory management libraries have there own caches of free memory which they would release after reaching a threshold .

Answer (score 0):

First of all the memory used by 3000 integers is very low and can't see a significant change in memory usage if you are checking memory using Task Manager . Also , as explained in other answers the STL containers do not deallocate immediately. 
There is a nice [forum](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/20025/) discussing memory allocation and deallocation by STL objects and object pointers.