# Freeing heap pointers stored in std::queue

Tags: c++, std

Consider this code:

```
class Foo;

std:queue<Foo*> q;

// allocate and add objects to the queue
for (int i=0; i<100000; i++)
{
    Foo* f = new Foo();
    q.push(f);
}

// remove objects from queue and free them
while (!q.empty())
{
    Foo* f2 = q.front();
    q.pop();
    delete f2;
}
```

By single-stepping I can see the Foo destructor getting called as each object is deleted, so I would expect the process memory usage to drop as each delete happens - but it doesn't. In my application the queue is used in producer/consumer threads and the memory usage just keeps growing.

The only way I have found to recover the memory is to swap the queue for an empty one whenever I have popped all items from it:

```
q.swap(std::queue<Foo*>());
```

If I use a vector rather than a queue, deleting the stored objects immediately drops process memory usage. Can anyone explain why the queue isn't behaving like that?

*Edit to clarify from the comments*: I understand that the queue manages the memory of the pointer variables themselves (i.e. 4 or 8 bytes per pointer), and that I can't control when *that* memory gets released. What I'm concerned about is that the heap memory being pointed to, which *I* am managing through new and delete, is also not being released on time.

*Edit 2: seems to only happen when the process is being debugged.. so not actually a problem in reality. Still weird though.

Comment: can you not use auto_ptr<Foo>? or If you have the freedom to use boost, use boost::tr1::shared_ptr.

Comment: @hagubear: Or, if you have the freedom to use a modern library, `std::unique_ptr`

Comment: you beat me to it @MikeSeymour :) I was crossing my finger and assuming that he/she is still in 4.8.1. auto_ptr is deprecated and replaced by unique_ptr in C++11 onwards

Comment: Same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21964251/stdqueue-memory-consumption-leads-to-memory-leak-c

Comment: How the containers manage their internal memory is implementation defined. Therefore it is always good to explicitly free the memory using the *swap idiom*.

Comment: @Galik understood about the internal memory - but memory being pointed to by each stored pointer value is also not being released. The queue is not managing that memory so why should queue implementation have any effect.

Comment: @incogn1to - similar but not exactly the same - see my edit

Comment: did u get the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Many implementations of delete/free may not always make all memory available again to the operating system right away – the memory might just be available for that process for awhile.  So if you are measuring your RSS or something, you can't necessarily expect it to go down the instant that something is deleted.  I think the behavior may be different here in debug mode, which would explain what you are seeing.